# querying multiple values from one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

we have a table called transaction_details.
when i write this query

```
SELECT 
DESCRIPTION,
item,
cust_code,
pack_description,
uos,
pack,
total_value,
total_value_vat,
total_value_goods,
price_indicator
from TRANSACTION_DETAILS
where cust_code=1273 
and item =371355
and item =371476
and item =371629
and item =370556
and item =370677
and item =370820
and item =370952
and item =371070
and item =371223
and item =372154
and item =372253
and item =371751
and item =371872
```

it shows me nothing in the result pane. we want to see the reult of these all the item one by one in single line of each item and dont want to be duplicate. thanks for helping.

Comment: I suspect you'll want to be using `OR` instead of `AND`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: This is too basic for dba.se - ask on SO instead?

Comment: It seems the operator you require is [relational division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449544/findout-duplicate-rows-in-a-table-while-inserting/6450663#6450663), commonly known as 'the supplier who supplies all parts'. Follow that link to Stack Overflow, then follow the 'relational-division' tag to view similar questions and possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
DESCRIPTION,
item,
cust_code,
pack_description,
uos,
pack,
total_value,
total_value_vat,
total_value_goods,
price_indicator
from TRANSACTION_DETAILS
where cust_code=1273 
and item in
(
    371355,
    371476,
    371629,
    370556,
    370677,
    370820,
    370952,
    371070,
    371223,
    372154,
    372253,
    371751,
    371872
)
```

As for duplicates, you're going to have to decide how you want duplicates handled.  Using a `GROUP BY`, if there *is* a duplicate `item` you will have to figure out how to aggregate the rest of the data for the result set.  Feel free to give me that info and I can write up your aggregate query.